# Can I apply Xamarin forms knowledge in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin

I am very interested in Xamarin, but because of my training I would also have to work in the area of WPF. My question is, Xamarin and WPF both use XAML and the MVVM pattern, Can I apply the knowledge of Xamarin in WPF as well?

Comment: Yes, there's a lot of overlap, but be aware that there are quite a few differences, too. Knowlede of Xamarin will definitely help with WPF, but the two are not interchangable.

Comment: Is MVVM in both of them quite similar, so that I can proceed fairly equal?

Comment: MVVM is a pattern, so it's platform independent. You can even use many of the same MVVM libraries for both, e.g. MVVMLight, MVVMCross.

Comment: okay, thanks for the fast answer :)

Comment: The thing that is probably going to catch you out are the controls that are very similar, but have just subtle differences, like different property names, not the same events etc.

Comment: Okay, I can still look at it separately, I'm just about to get in touch with XAML and MVMM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it has very good similarities. even with the controls too with slight differences. For example, stackpanel in WPF is available in Xamarin as StackLayout.
You can look into

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/building-cross-platform-applications/case-study-tasky

These are some of the links that helped me.

Answer (score 0):

XAML is XML and WPF uses it too so yes, this is essentially the same language and the graphs are similar, an C# is used in both cases which clearly helps too.

Comment: XAML isn't *similar* to XML, XML **is** XML!

Comment: Sorry I did not want to offend you

Comment: Since both Xamarin and WPF use XAML, the whole XML point is a bit moot anyway... :)

Comment: you wee using exclamation mark, it is a sign of being angry?